# How to return value from nested anonymous function javascript

Tags: javascript, function, anonymous-function, nested-function

How can I return value from bellow inner anonymous function.

```
function getDayFromCalendar() {
    var db = openDatabase('Calendar', '1.0', 'myapp', 2 * 1024 * 1024);
    db.transaction(function (tx) {
        tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM calendar LIMIT 1', [], function (tx, results) {
            return results.rows.item(0).date;
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: At the moment you're only returning results.rows.item(0).date to the function getDayFromCalendar. You're not returning anything from getDayFromCalendar.

Comment: Also, if items is an array rather than a function, you should index it using [0], not (0).

Comment: AFAIU `tx.executeSql` is async. So you can't. You have to change approach to async.

Comment: @hindmost any other way to re-write this function

Answer (score 0):

```
function getDayFromCalendar() {
    var db = openDatabase('Calendar', '1.0', 'myapp', 2 * 1024 * 1024);
    var outerResult = db.transaction(function (tx) {
        var innerResult = tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM calendar LIMIT 1', [], function (tx, results) {
            return results.rows.item(0).date;
        });
        // here you have inner function result
        return innerResult;
    });
    // here you have outer function result
    alert(outerResult);
}
```

Comment: nope still I get undefined.I think that last line "alert" executes first and then inner function executing